# when should we use the OnCompleteListener() for queries

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase to develop a small app, I read that the `Persistence(true)` will queue the requests and execute them when the users have a connection. I put some codes in `OnCompleteListener` but they will not be executed when the users are offline and the data will become wrong when the users go online (after restarting the app ). so, should I move the codes out of `OnCompleteListener()` ? When should I use `OnCompleteListener` ?

And when I open the app again . the requests execute but the OnCompleteListener does not fire. anyone, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've found Firebase Realtime Database's `OnCompleteListener`s fire when the data has been written to the database on the server, and they are not persisted across app restarts.

I typically use `OnCompleteListener` to detect problems in writing, such as security rules rejecting the write operation.

You *can* also use `OnCompleteListener` to for example mark a messages as "delivered" to the database, but that requires some more work on your side to also handle the app restart scenario.

For example: writes of each client are executed in the order in which you call the API. So if you perform a token write when the app starts, and wait for the `OnCompleteListener`'s success of that one, you can be certain that writes that were submitted before the app restart have completed.

Comment: is there any way to "clean" the requests when the users go offline ? because, I am trying to perform ```OnCompleteListener``` , but "they are not persisted across app restarts." as you said. the data will become wrong if they not perform ```onCompleteListener```

Comment: You can call `purgeOutstandingWrites`: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase.html#purgeOutstandingWrites()

Comment: thanks Frank, I will try and let you know as soon as posible

Comment: btw, do you have any example for  purgeOutstandingWrites () ? thanks

Comment: `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().purgeOutstandingWrites()`?